# Perform a Post using URLSession and waitsForConnectivity in background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, urlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I want to post a json using URLSession when the connection is active. For that, I'm using `URLSessionConfiguration`and setting `configuration.waitsForConnectivity = true`
and it works fine.
my problem is when the App goes to background before the performing the Post and even the connectivity is available nothing happens ! so I changed `URLSessionConfiguration` to use background mode:

```
 let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: BackgroundSession.identifier)
configuration.waitsForConnectivity = true
```

but same problem :/
Is there any way to start the Post even the App is in background mode.

Comment: Did you enable background fetch?
Go to project target -> Capabilities -> enable Background Modes -> check Background Fetch

Comment: is not possible to tell what the problem could be with the provided information but, notice that for a background session `waitsForConnectivity` is ignored. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/2908812-waitsforconnectivity?language=objc